# Return the_content() with formatting inside a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, shortcode

I'm trying to create an extra shortcode to display `the_content`

```
function custom_recipe_content( $atts ){                
    if ( ! is_singular( 'recipe' ) ) {
        return;
    }               
    return the_content();           
}
add_shortcode( 'recipe_content', 'custom_recipe_content' );
```

When I add the `[recipe_content]` shortcode inside a wp text widget, it's added above the widget rather than inside the widget.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, thanks to TRS:

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content(), get_the_ID() );

    return $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning

```
apply_filters('the_content',the_content());
```

This will implement the content as content.

Comment: Even that doesn't work. The content is being returned just fine. I think the problem is that the code inside the text widget, `echo` is being used.